# How to configure maven multi-module project in Eclipse or Netbeans to reduce deploy time

Tags: deployment, time, project, maven, reduce

I have the following project structure

- project-parent: All the parent configuration is here
- project-ear: Assemblying the ear file from the ejb, war and core projects
- project-ejb: EJB module depends on core
- project-war: Web module depends on EJB and core
- project-core: no dependencies

I was able to use able to use Eclipse or Netbeans and deploy the project from the IDE to glassfish. But what I want is whenever I make changes to the webmodule I want it to be deployed automatically. So that I refresh the browser and see the changes.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your problem exactly is (hot deployment works fine for me when using GFv3 with both Eclipse and NetBeans). Maybe clarify.

Just in case, if you need to run a maven build but don't want to start a *full* reactor build, maybe consider using the advanced reactor options (more precisely `-pl` to specify a specific project  with `-am` to build all of the projects that the specified project depends upon) when calling `mvn`. See the blog post  [Maven Tips and Tricks: Advanced Reactor Options](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/) for more details.